# apply higher specificity with SVG attribute

Tags: svg

Is it possible to **not** fill circle1 green, and have the `fill="url(#star)"` be applied to it,
without removing the `<style>` definition?

In other words: give the attribute `fill=` setting a higher specificity (or `!important` need be)

[image]

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 230 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
   #circle1 {
     fill:green; /* higher specificity */
   }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="star" viewBox="0,0,10,10" width="10%" height="10%">
      <polygon points="0,0 2,5 0,10 5,8 10,10 8,5 10,0 5,2"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50"  cy="30" r="30" fill="url(#star)"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150"  cy="30" r="30" fill="url(#star)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inline `style` attribute:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 230 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
   #circle1 {
     fill:green; /* higher specificity */
   }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="star" viewBox="0,0,10,10" width="10%" height="10%">
      <polygon points="0,0 2,5 0,10 5,8 10,10 8,5 10,0 5,2"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50"  cy="30" r="30" style="fill: url(#star)"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150"  cy="30" r="30" fill="url(#star)"/>
</svg>
```